# Xcode 12: test.a(dataCollectKey.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for macOS, for architecture x86_64

Tags: ios, xcode

My project linked a static framework `.a` file, which works perfect under Xcode 11. But when I upgraded to Xcode 12 I got error:

```
In /test.a(dataCollectKey.o), building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for macOS, for architecture x86_64
```

I didn't get the point, x86_64 should be for iPhone simulator architecture, then why comes this error, any helps? thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you had any success on this issue? I have the same issue with a third party library

Comment: You could disable the framework for the simulator then should works.